# Sequential quadratic programming source

Tags: optimization, reference-request, nonlinear-programming, quadratic-programming

What are the good text books to learn SQP? Are there any online courses that you can suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest reading [Numerical Optimization](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5) by Nocedal and Wright. It has a pretty neat chapter devoted to SQP methods.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @fpacaud 's recommendation of the Nocedal and Wright book.

Another source which is complementary to the Nocedal and Wright book, and is more in-depth in certain areas, is the 125 page long [Chapter 15, "Sequential Quadratic Programming Methods"](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9780898719857.ch15) in "[Trust Region Methods" by Andrew R. Conn, Nicholas I. M. Gould, and Philippe L. Toint](https://my.siam.org/Store/Product/viewproduct/?ProductId=897). In particular, that chapter can be bought as an electronic purchase of that individual chapter for \$14.95  (edit: \$19.99 as of Nov 2022, the ravages of inflation) https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9780898719857.ch15 .

Answer (score 3):

In the book *Nonlinear Optimization* (2010) by Bomze, Demyanov, Fletcher and Telarky, there is the chapter [The Sequential Quadratic Programming Method](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-11339-0_3) written by Fletcher.

Comment: Available as a freebie at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226679871_The_Sequential_Quadratic_Programming_Method .

Answer (score 3):

The use of SQP to solve interesting technical problems can be seen in [this work](http://hqp.sourceforge.net/omuses.pdf) (pp. 26-31). In addition, a project [HQP](http://omuses.github.io/hqp/doc/html/index.html) developed for over 20 years is available on this site free of charge.